# How do you pickle figure objects in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pickle

I am getting the following error:

> ImportError: No module named gdbm

I'm using this to pickle:

```
pickle.dump(fig1, file('test_1.pickle','wb'))
```

where fig1 is just a figure object in matplotlib:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
```

Can Anyone help? I'm running Python 2.7.6 and matplotlib 1.3.1

Comment: When does the `ImportError` occur?  When running the `pickle.dump` or earlier in your script?  Properly reported errors require some context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error message you get has anything to do with the code you are showing. Python can't find the module `gdbm`. Maybe you want to use `dbm` instead of `gdbm`?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you want to do with `dbm`. Maybe you could open a new thread explaining what you actually want to do with `dbm`.

Comment: I am not necessarily trying to do anything, I'm just trying to pickle an object. Is this possible?

Comment: In other words without that piece of code, I do not get the error. Any help?

Comment: The line involving `pickle.dump` works perfectly fine on my machine if I do a `import pickle` before calling it. You don't provide enough context on where the import error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
pickle.dump(fig1, open('test_1.pickle','wb'))
```

not

```
pickle.dump(fig1, file('test_1.pickle','wb'))
```

It needs an `open`